# php script in bash loop

Tags: php, bash, while-loop

I'm a beginner bash coder, and have a PHP script; in each run it returns 0 or 1 and I need a bash script that runs this PHP script until it returns 1.

PHP script:

```
/* sample code */
echo $number;
```

Bash script:

```
#!/bin/bash    
output=`php /var/www/site/script.php`
while [$output == 1]
do
output=`php /var/www/site/script.php`
done
```

The PHP script is working, but the bash script doesn't work

Bash returns

```
$ bash /root/loop.sh
/root/loop.sh: line 6: syntax error near unexpected token `done'
```

Comment: I have provided an answer below. Clearly *someone* didn't like it, but please let me know if it's helpful.

Answer (score 0):

use the syntax corret in while, try:

```
#!/bin/bash    
output=`php /var/www/site/script.php`
while [ "$output" -eq 1 ];
do
output=`php /var/www/site/script.php`
done
```

Comment: /root/loop.sh: line 6: syntax error near unexpected token `done'. Not loop. And php script running once

Answer (score 0):

So, your PHP script is not "returning" 1, it's echoing 1 to standard output. If you have it actually return 1, you can make better use of your while loop. Consider these two scripts:

## foo.php

```
#!/usr/bin/env php
<?php

if (rand(1, 10) == 3) {
    exit(1);
} else {
    exit(0);
}
```

## foo.sh

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
while ./foo.php
do
    echo -n "."
done
echo "done"
```

If we make both executable (`chmod +x foo.php; chmod +x foo.sh`) we can run `./foo.sh` from the command line.

```
mike ~ $ ./foo.sh
.....done
mike ~ $ ./foo.sh
..................done
mike ~ $ ./foo.sh
...done
```

What's happening? `while` looks at the return value of the command it runs; if it's a zero, it keeps going, otherwise it stops. Typically we see it running the `[` command* but we can have it run any arbitrary command such as a PHP script.

*That's right, those square brackets are not syntactical and `[` is a command — run `ls -l /bin/[` if you don't believe me! This was one problem with your existing script, it had no spaces around `[` and `]`.

Comment: Folks who down vote without comment are just the worst.

Comment: yet this error. /root/foo.sh: line 7: syntax error: unexpected end of file

Comment: There are not 7 lines in the script I posted

Comment: solved. due to the extra characters ^M that puts windows

Comment: No problem; if this was helpful, please upvote it. If it answered your question, please mark as accepted, so it doesn't continue to show as un-answered. Thanks.